# REPNZ SCAS Assembly Instruction Specifics

Tags: assembly, x86, reverse-engineering, strlen

I am trying to reverse engineer a binary and the following instruction is confusing me, can anyone clarify what exactly this does?

```
=>0x804854e:    repnz scas al,BYTE PTR es:[edi]
  0x8048550:    not    ecx
```

Where:

```
EAX: 0x0
ECX: 0xffffffff
EDI: 0xbffff3dc ("aaaaaa\n")
ZF:  1
```

I see that it is somehow decrementing ECX by 1 each iteration, and that EDI is incrementing along the length of the string.  I know it calculates the length of the string, but as far as exactly HOW it's happening, and why "al" is involved I'm not quite sure.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I'll try to explain it by reversing the code back into C.

Intel's Instruction Set Reference (Volume 2 of [Software Developer's Manual](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html)) is invaluable for this kind of reverse engineering.

### REPNE SCASB

The logic for REPNE and SCASB combined:

```c
while (ecx != 0) {
    temp = al - *(BYTE *)edi;
    SetStatusFlags(temp);
    if (DF == 0)   // DF = Direction Flag
        edi = edi + 1;
    else
        edi = edi - 1;
    ecx = ecx - 1;
    if (ZF == 1) break;
}
```

Or more simply:

```c
while (ecx != 0) {
    ZF = (al == *(BYTE *)edi);
    if (DF == 0)
        edi++;
    else
        edi--;
    ecx--;
    if (ZF) break;
}
```

### String Length

However, the above is insufficient to explain how it computes the length of a string. Based on the presence of the `not ecx` in your question, I'm assuming the snippet belongs to this idiom (or similar) for computing string length using `REPNE SCASB`:

```c
sub ecx, ecx
sub al, al
not ecx
cld
repne scasb
not ecx
dec ecx
```

Translating to C and using our logic from the previous section, we get:

```c
ecx = (unsigned)-1;
al = 0;
DF = 0;
while (ecx != 0) {
    ZF = (al == *(BYTE *)edi);
    if (DF == 0)
        edi++;
    else
        edi--;
    ecx--;
    if (ZF) break;
}
ecx = ~ecx;
ecx--;
```

Simplifying using `al = 0` and `DF = 0`:

```c
ecx = (unsigned)-1;
while (ecx != 0) {
    ZF = (0 == *(BYTE *)edi);
    edi++;
    ecx--;
    if (ZF) break;
}
ecx = ~ecx;
ecx--;
```

Things to note:

- in two's complement notation, flipping the bits of `ecx` is equivalent to `-1 - ecx`.
- in the loop, `ecx` is decremented before the loop breaks, so it decrements by `length(edi) + 1` in total.
- `ecx` can never be zero in the loop, since the string would have to occupy the entire address space.

So after the loop above, `ecx` contains `-1 - (length(edi) + 1)` which is the same as `-(length(edi) + 2)`, which we flip the bits to give `length(edi) + 1`, and finally decrement to give `length(edi)`.

Or rearranging the loop and simplifying:

```c
const char *s = edi;
size_t c = (size_t)-1;      // c == -1
while (*s++ != '\0') c--;   // c == -1 - length(s)
c = ~c;                     // c == length(s)
```

And inverting the count:

```c
size_t c = 0;
while (*s++ != '\0') c++;
```

which is the `strlen` function from C:

```c
size_t strlen(const char *s) {
    size_t c = 0;
    while (*s++ != '\0') c++;
    return c;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the conversion to a HOL - very helpful in understanding what is going on.

Comment: What is *(BYTE *)?

Comment: @user12140617 *(BYTE *)edi means something along the lines of "cast edi to a type of BYTE*, then dereference." Hope this helps.

Answer (score 22):

`AL` is involved, because `scas` scans the memory for the value of `AL`. `AL` has been zeroed so that the instruction finds the terminating zero at the end of the string. `scas` itself increments (or decrements, depending on the direction flag) `EDI` automatically. The `REPNZ` prefix (which is more readable in the `REPNE` form) repeats the `scas` as long as the comparison is false (**REP**eat while **N**ot **E**qual) and `ECX > 0`. It also decrements `ECX` automatically in every iteration. `ECX` has been initialized to the longest possible string so that it doesn't terminate the loop early.

Since `ECX` counts down from `0xffffffff` (also known as -1), the resulting length will be `-1-ECX` which due to the peculiarity of 2's complement arithmetic can be calculated using a `NOT` instruction.

Comment: Great, that makes perfect sense now.  Thanks!

Comment: Maybe I'm lazy, but when I did a Google search for "repne scas", this is the answer I was looking for, so I didn't have to download the instruction set manual and read it myself. So thanks for enabling my laziness. ;)

Answer (score 4):

It compares the byte at `es:[edi]` to whatever in `al` is and repeats this step until either `ecx` becomes zero or the value at `es:[edi]` matches the value in `al`. After each step, `edi` is incremented so it points to the next byte in memory.
The program applies `not` to the counter (ecx) afterwards, based on the following instruction.

`repnz` means "repeat until zero flag is not set *and* cx is not zero". Each iteration decrements `ecx`.
`scas` or more precisely `scasb` compares the value in `al` to the memory operand (always `es:[edi]` or `es:[di]` depending on address size), then sets the flags accordingly (zero flag will be set if the two values equal) and increments (or decrements, based on the direction flag) `edi`.

Comment: Not repeat **until**, repeat **while** ZF!=0 && ECX.