# what is the NOT instruction doing to eax in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, reverse-engineering, strlen, twos-complement

```
repnz scas al,BYTE PTR es:[edi
MOV eax,ecx
NOT eax
```

value of eax changed from  0xfffffffc to 0x3 after these lines.

Comment: From you example, I would say it looks like a bit-wise not.

Comment: just for clarification, so it changes the binary to 11 which is equal to 3?

Comment: Yes each bit is flipped.

Comment: In this instance (combined with `repnz scas`) it's easier to think about the "arithmetic meaning" of `not eax` which is `eax = -eax - 1`. That is equivalent to saying that all bits are flipped, just a different way to think about it.

Comment: what is `repnz scas` contributing in the situation here?

Comment: `ecx` is decremented for each character `repnz scas` handles, having a `not` after it [is a common idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26783797/555045)

Comment: so its always ecx that will get decremented when `repnz scas` is used?

Comment: [It's a well-known pattern to implement `strlen`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26783797/repnz-scas-assembly-instruction-specifics), well one of many.

Comment: If you're not sure what an instruction does (e.g. whether `repns scasb` will decrement ECX), look it up in the manual: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/rep:repe:repz:repne:repnz